# Polymer 1.0: How do I individually set the width of paper-dropdown boxes?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, width, polymer, polymer-1.0

The paper menu items are fine. I just need to change the width of the selected/non-selected value:

[image: paper-dropdown-menu]

I've tried styling like this in the paper-dropdown-menu tag:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu 
id="districtDropdown" 
selected-item="{{selectedDistrict}}"
selected-item-label="{{selected}}"
label='&#65290;District' 
style="width:800px; 
display:inline-block;" 
noink no-animations>
```

but I can only change the width up to a certain point (like the picture above), and then it does not get any wider.

Here's a isolated test I have done, that does not change the width of the paper-dropdown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<title>test </title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax-form/ajax-form.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<style is="custom-style">
  paper-dropdown-menu {
    --paper-dropdown-menu: {
      width: 800px;
    }
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `paper-dropdown-menu` [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu), you should use the `--paper-dropdown-menu` mixin to style it. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzgy954f/) with an example and here's the custom css you need for the mixin:

```
<style is="custom-style"> <!-- or just the <style> tag in a <dom-module>'s template -->
  paper-dropdown-menu {
    --paper-dropdown-menu: {
      width: 800px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

For more info on custom CSS mixins check this [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins).

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts from the fiddle into your answer.

Comment: @Alan, are you completely certain your example is able to change the width to 800px? I edited the value from 300px to 800px, and I see no difference. Please see the test I have added to my question.

Comment: @VagueExplanation did you click on run again? I can change the width 800px or whatever other value and see the result like that.

Comment: Yes I hit run, but result just displays the plain text "Croissant Donut Financier Madeleine". Regardless, I tried running the code that I added to my question, and the defined width has no effect on the drop down box on either Firefox, Safari or Chrome. Try the code I added to my question with the correct file paths to components. Does the size change work for you?

Comment: It's really odd that you just get plain text, here's a screenshot of what I see in Chrome 46 for that fiddle (changing the width to 800px) http://i.imgur.com/aUGfH4U.png  My guess would be that the imports from polygit are getting blocked for you, because otherwise that code should do what you want...